# freeswitch forbidden gateway error

Tags: ubuntu, voip, sip, freeswitch

i've stuck into a strange problem, i have Ubuntu 12.04 with static IP, installed Freeswitch with FusionPBX with easy install script from here http://wiki.fusionpbx.com/index.php?title=Easy_FusionPBX

everything is working Freeswitch , FusionPBX GUI, i have tried everything searched google , forums but didn't find any solution to this problem,

whenever i tried to register Gateway with my provider which is IDT Express, for internal when trying out of the box extension from x-lite got this error

2014-03-17 14:59:43.427289 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:2576 Cant register a pointer. 2014-03-17 14:59:43.427289 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:1486 SIP auth failure (REGISTER) on sofia profile 'internal' for [1000@mystaticip] from ip 124.155.243.69

and for external for gateway registration 2014-03-17 14:54:27.727289 [NOTICE] sofia_reg.c:423 Registering 228ffc0e-d106-40b2-b992-7bb0c616d7cf 2014-03-17 14:54:27.827310 [ERR] sofia_reg.c:2110 228ffc0e-d106-40b2-b992-7bb0c616d7cf Registration Failed with status Forbidden [403]. failure #32

right now i'm in urgent need of external SIP users

please help

Thanks